# Phonegap and web view

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova

I am new to Phonegap and android development, so far I've been doing some great stuff but now I am facing two major issues:

-How to upload images through the html . I don't want the image to be uploaded through ajax and go to the server, I want it to be submitted with the form.

-How to load the locally saved assets(js and css) from a remote url so that the app loads much faster.

Comment: Yeah but still the fact is that I am stuck :/

Comment: haha, yeah m tryin hard.